# Android: Retrofit+RxJava send POST request to local server. I've receive - retrofit.HttpException: HTTP 404 Not Found.

Tags: android, http, retrofit, rx-java

I worked on Android project (Android Studio 1.4).
I want to connect to my Apache server (not REST API) to receive data from him. important NOTICE: I've made the same queries to my server for SWIFT iOS project, I was successfully get POST/GET request, so server is set up and working well. I want to do the same for Android.
Bellow code:

1) My Service.proto file. I've used protobuf between my client and server.

```
option java_outer_classname = "Service";
message BaseModelRequestProtobufDTO 
{
    required string name = 1;
    required string model = 2;
}
message BaseModelResponseProtobufDTO 
{
    required string response = 1;
}
```

2) Using the library 'com.squareup.wire:wire-runtime:1.8.0', 
I've got Java classes - **BaseModelRequestProtobufDTO** and  **BaseModelResponseProtobufDTO**

3) My Retrofit interface:

```
public interface RetrofitService {

   public interface RetrofitService 
{
    @Headers({"Cookie: bank=*************", "Content-Type: **************"})
    @POST("/baseMethod")
    Observable{BaseModelResponseProtobufDTO} baseRequest(@Body BaseModelRequestProtobufDTO baseModelRequestProtobufDTO);
}
```

4) my function **login** take login and password, send to server. I want to receive response from him.

```
public static void login(String login, String password){
    Log.v("json", "enter in Login = " );
    // Prepare data as JSON object
    Map<String,String> dictionary = new HashMap<>();
    dictionary.put("password", password);
    dictionary.put("login", login);

    JSONObject JSONData = new JSONObject(dictionary);
    String JSONModel = JSONData.toString();

    Log.v("json", JSONModel);

    UFCRequest loginRequest = new  UFCRequest("login", JSONModel);

    Log.v("json",loginRequest.baseModel.toString());
    Log.v("json",loginRequest.getBaseModel().toString());

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://77.108.126.41:8080/AAA/endpointshttp/protobuf")
            .addConverterFactory(WireConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();
    RetrofitService retrofitService = retrofit.create(RetrofitService.class);
    retrofitService.baseRequest(loginRequest.getBaseModel())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber{BaseModelResponseProtobufDTO}() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    Log.v("json", "onCompleted");

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.v("json", "onError " + e);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(BaseModelResponseProtobufDTO baseModelResponseProtobufDTO) {
                    Log.v("json", baseModelResponseProtobufDTO.response.toString());

                    Log.v("json", "onNext");
                }
            });

     }
```

I send protobuf object to server, It's contain two string field **name** and **model**. **name** is simple string name. **model** is string which was obtained from json object which in turn was emmited from dictionary. Dictionary is login and password.

5) My gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.squareup.wire:wire-runtime:1.8.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-wire:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1'
}
```

6) My result :
I've receive - **retrofit.HttpException: HTTP 404 Not Found.**

What I'm doing wrong? Please!

Comment: it means that your url is wrong

Comment: May I call server through retrofit if it's not REST api? Simple server

Comment: @ Tauqir, you were right. Omg, retrofit + rxjava works perfetc.  @POST("http://77.108.126.41:8080/AAA/endpointshttp/protobuf/baseMethod"). Thnx a lot

Comment: Problem solved. Closed.

Comment: @Gilb007 i have same problem, why dont you post the solution ?

Comment: @MBH the solution is right to appoint endpoint to server in your retrofit interface => @POST("77.108.126.41:8080/AAA/endpointshttp/protobuf/baseMethod") , other code above is the same. If your have question please write here.

Answer (score 0):

In BaseUrl 
`.baseUrl("http://77.108.126.41:8080/AAA/endpointshttp/protobuf")`, you need to end with '/' 
.baseUrl("http://77.108.126.41:8080/AAA/endpointshttp/protobuf/")