# Android RxJava2 : how setup a right async observable consuming REST API?

Tags: android, rx-java2

My code is:

```
RestClient client = new RestClient();
        Disposable subscribe = client.getApiMovie().getTopRated()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe( data -> { Log.d("mytag", data.body().toString()) });
```

Is that code right.
PS: I'm using Android Studio 2, how can I set it up in order to use lambda expression?

my RestClient constructor:

```
//what adapter shall I use?
    public RestClient(){
            if( client == null ) {
                client = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .client(getHttpClient())
                        .build();
            }
        }
```

build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.username.sunshine.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

Lambda syntax should now work by adding 
jackOptions and compileOptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are gonna use Retrofit with Rx, don't forget to add call adapter for Rx.

```
client = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .client(getHttpClient())
                    .build();
```

If you are doing like this, you are doing right. For better mapping, rest client should return an Observable with your object, like `Observable<List<Movie>> getApiMovie();` and this will return a list of movies. Movie object should contains all properties from api annotated with `@SerializedName("objectName")`.

Because you are using RxJava 2, use `.addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())` with dependency `compile 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'`. More details here [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter).

Comment: I'm using RxJava 2, and when I try to write RxJava(CallAdapterFactory), the only hint I've got from Android Studio 2, are RxThreadFactory, RxAndroidPlugins and RxJavaPlugins, so I'm supposing I don't have that RxJavaCallAdapterFactory, it's that possible?

Comment: Using RxJava2CallAdapter , I get this: 
`com.jakewharton.retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.HttpException: HTTP 404 Not Found`

Comment: Url is inexistent. Chech your url if is correct or find if realy exist.

Comment: But I'm not using that manually or intentionally, I believe it's used by `.addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())`

Comment: No. Is not. That converter is used to transform retrofit responses into Observables. Is still your url.

Comment: Found it here 
`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32964656/android-retrofitrxjava-send-post-request-to-local-server-ive-receive-retro`

Comment: Exception was converted using `RxJava2CallAdapterFactory` from Retrofit HttpException to `Observable` so it can be throwed to `onError()` implementation. Is still your url problem. In what is writed your server? I assume is personal.

Comment: I'm just learning how to build Android Apps using public themoviedb APIs, now it's fixed.

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: As u said, wrong URL in the baseUrl of the APIService
`@GET("/movie/top_rated")
   Observable<MovieResults> getTopRated();
`
I removed the first forward slash.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is right, your api client has to return Observable. 
Retrofit library can utilize 'adapter factory' for returning observables.
In case this is your custom RestClient and you create Observable manually, don't
forget to use Observable.defer(()- > yourTask).
There is a library called Retrolambda, it allows to use lambdas, but, I faced issue, that it is not working with latest AndroidStudio and AndroidStudio suggest to use Jack instead. Right now I use Retrolambda.

Comment: My problem is that I can't use that sintax (->/lambda) in Android Studio 2 and also I didn't setup any adapter in my custom client.